# JavaFX stop Timeline

Tags: animation, javafx, timeline

I use FXML. I've created a button to stop/restart a live chart. For the animation I've used Timeline. I'would like to control it from the guiController (from an other class), but it is not working. How can I stop a Timeline from an other class?

Thank you!

FXML:

```
            <Button id="button" layoutX="691.0" layoutY="305.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btn_startmes" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="115.0" text="%start" />
```

guiController:

```
@FXML      
private void btn_stopmes(ActionEvent event) {
  MotionCFp Stopping = new MotionCFp();
Stopping.animation.stop();
}
```

MotionCFp.java:

```
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
       else{
        ResourceBundle motionCFp = ResourceBundle.getBundle("motionc.fp.Bundle", new Locale("en", "EN"));
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(MotionCFp.class.getResource("gui.fxml"), motionCFp);
        final guiController gui = new guiController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle(motionCFp.getString("title"));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);        
        root.getChildren().add(gui.createChart());
                animation = new Timeline();
                animation.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000/60), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                // 6 minutes data per frame
                for(int count=0; count < 6; count++) {
                    gui.nextTime();
                    gui.plotTime();
                    animation.pause();
                    animation.play();
                }
            }
        }));
        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        stage.show();
        animation.play();
       } 

   }
```

Comment: [timeline.stop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html#stop%28%29) - my guess is that you already know this, but need to provide more info in your question (e.g. short executable sample code plus description) which illustrates what your real issue is so that somebody can be of more assistance.

Comment: I've tried it. I use FXML, so there is a guiControll, which handles eg the button actions. And there is a main class in which the Timeline is created. And I can't start/stop/restart the animation from the guiController. If the Timeline is started (for infinite time) I am not able to stop it with a button.

Comment: Please include in your question, executable code for your FXML, controller class and application class, so that the issue can be replicated.  Thanks.

Comment: I've copied the related parts of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a reference in your controller to the original animation created in the start method of your application.  This will allow you to code the button event handler in the controller to stop the animation.

The `MotionCFp` class can contain the code:

```
final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
  getClass().getResource("gui.fxml"), 
  ResourceBundle.getBundle("motionc.fp.Bundle", new Locale("en", "EN"))
);
final Pane root = (Pane) loader.load();
final GuiController controller = loader.<GuiController>getController();
...
animation = new Timeline();
controller.setAnimation(animation);
```

And the `GuiController` class can contain the code:

```
private Timeline animation;

public void setAnimation(Timeline animation) {
  this.animation = animation;
}

@FXML private void btn_stopmes(ActionEvent event) {
  if (animation != null) {
    animation.stop();
  }
}
```

MotionCFp is your application class.  You only need one instance of it.  That instance is created by the the JavaFX launcher, you should never do `new MotionCFp()`.

Please note that these kinds of questions are much easier to answer quickly and correctly if the code in the question is [simple, complete, compilable and executable](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will do as you said next time. But there is an error message at guiControll, with:   

public setAnimation(Timeline animation) {
  this.animation = animation; 
}

It says invalid method declaration. return type required.

Comment: Yep I missed the return type, fixed in the answer now - I should compile my answer code too ;-)